# Quickblox, hybrid apps and video recording

Tags: cordova, quickblox, videochat

2 questions with respect to Qucikblox, for a cross platform phonegap based video chat app:

Does quickblox have APIs for a phonegap based cross platform app?

Does quickblox servers have the capacity to record video chats, if there is business case?